# How would I return a specific json value which has duplicate keys

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following JSON

```
{
  "nest1" : {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "irrelevant",
      "url" : "irrelevant"
    },
    "key" : "value1"
  },
  "nest2" : {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "irrelevant",
      "url" : "irrelevant"
    },
    "key" : "value2"
  }
}
```

I have tried something like below to grab the value for the second`key`, but this throws an `InvalidOperationException`. with the following error message:

> Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.

```
string value = getJson(json, "key");
```

The method looks like

```
public string getJson(string json, string name)
    {
       JObject token = JObject.Parse(json);
       JToken jtoken = token.Last.ToString();
       return jtoken[name].toString();
    }
```

I'm guessing there is probably something simple i'm forgetting, any help would be great

Comment: You know that the [...] at the start and end are largely unnecessary, right? You're creating an extra array that contains one object that contains multiple keyed objects. Your JSON structure needs a bit of cleanup.

Comment: Yeah I parse that out, wasn't suppose to put that in there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You're using `ToString()` incorrectly. If you implicitly convert a `string` to `JToken` like you do, the resulting `JToken` contains the *text*, not the object the string represents. So you should get rid of the call to `ToString()`.
2. `Last` doesn't return the value of `nest2`, it returns the whole property. To get just the value of the last property, you can use something like `token.PropertyValues().Last()`.

So, your code could look like this:

```
public static string GetJson(string json, string name)
{
    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
    JToken lastValue = obj.PropertyValues().Last();
    return lastValue[name].Value<string>();
}
```

I have also changed the last `ToString()` to `Value<string>()`, because I think it makes more sense here, even though it doesn't change the result.

Comment: I think writing code depending on the order of properties ( `Last()` ) should be something to avoid.

Comment: @L.B Probably, yeah. But that's what was in the question and doing something else would mean I would have to guess what is the code actually meant to do and what are the possible inputs.

Comment: @LB you're probably right. Although i don't believe the order will ever change from the JSON I'm receiving, this seems to be the only way to pick out that value without deserializing

Answer (score 2):

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var item in dynObj)
{
    foreach (var subitem in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("url:" + subitem.attributes.url);
        Console.WriteLine("key:" + subitem.key);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how will `dynamic` actually help here (apart from making the syntax a bit nicer).

Comment: This doesn't compile for me, doesn't like doing a `foreach` on the `dynObj`

Comment: @AdamSweeney It works for me. What compilation error do you get?

Comment: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Collection.IEnumerable' because 'System.Collections.IEnumerable` does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumberator'

Comment: Strange. My conf: VS2010 + .Net 4.0 + Json.Net 4.5

Comment: @LB Actually the issue was I wasn't using `Microsoft.CSharp.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a misconception. In this case there are two a principal object that have two properties:

```
Principal {
  var1;
  var2
}
```

Same thing to the properties. Do you need a array of objects?

```
[ { "objects" :
   [ 
    {
      "attributes" : {
         "type" : "irrelevant",
         "url" : "irrelevant"
      },
      "key" : "value1"
    },
    {
      "attributes" : {
      "type" : "irrelevant",
      "url" : "irrelevant"
       },
      "key" : "value2"
     }
  ]
} ]
```

Comment: I don't have any control over the JSON, it's just what I get as a response